# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+2,n+1)}{\Gamma(n+2)\,n^3\,(1+\tfrac1n)^{n+1}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, lambert-w

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$

$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

This is a follow up question to the 
[recently asked one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3579498/122782).

Is there a closed form for the sum

\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\frac{\Gamma(n+2,n+1)}{\Gamma(n+2)\,n^3\,(1+\tfrac1n)^{n+1}}
\tag{1a}\label{1a}
\\
&=
1-\frac1\e\,\left(2+\int_0^1 \frac{\Wp(-\tfrac t\e)}{\Wm(-\tfrac t\e)}\, dt\right)
\approx 0.20861152792812846
\tag{1b}\label{1b}
,
\end{align}
where $\Wp,\Wm$ are the two real branches of the Lambert W function?

Not sure, if this is of any use, but
the numeric value of the sum is surprisingly close to $\frac\Omega\e$,
where $\Omega=\W(1)$,

\begin{align}
\left|S-\frac\Omega\e\right|&<3\cdot10^{-5}
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Related sequence of fractions
\begin{align}
A_n&=\exp(n+1)\cdot
\frac{\Gamma(n+2,n+1)}{\Gamma(n+2)\,n^3\,(1+\tfrac1n)^{n+1}}
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}

is:
\begin{align}
\left[
\frac54,
\frac {13}{27},
\frac {103}{256},
\frac {4388}{9375},
\frac {30575}{46656},
\frac {850914}{823543},
\frac {1335923603}{754974720},
\frac {43671523328}{13559717115},
\frac {429970430763}{70000000000},
\dots
\right]
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}

The numerators and denominators of \eqref{4}:

\begin{align}
&\left[
5,
13,
103,
4388,
30575,
850914,
1335923603,
43671523328,
429970430763,
\dots
\right]
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
&\left[
4,
27,
256,
9375,
46656,
823543,
754974720,
13559717115,
70000000000,
\dots
\right]
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

$\endgroup$

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

For sure, it is really nice to see $\Omega$ and $e$ appearing so simply and I like it, be sure.

However, at this level of accuracy, you could find many *coincidences*. For example
$$S=\frac{53+1367 e-391 e^2}{3 \left(-236+237 e+135 e^2\right)}$$ is correct for almost $20$ significant figures.

In the same way,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{W_0(-\frac te)}{W_{-1}(-\frac te)}\, dt\sim \frac{7188}{23885+2 \sqrt{169014673} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{617823390329}{169014673 \sqrt{169014673}}\right)\right)}$$is correct for almost $20$ significant figures. This is the reciprocal of the largets root of $2396 x^3-23885 x^2+55854 x-17749=0$.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, sure, inverse symbolic calculators can find plenty. 
Just $\Omega$ looks natural here, and it was tempting to look at 
the integral in the linked question
as $I\approx \mathrm{e}-2-\Omega$.

Comment: @g.kov. I totally agree on all points. As I wrote it, I like your approximation very much; simple an beautiful. By the way, +1.